# Disabling commandButton in VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

EDIT:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" rerender="IdPanel" 
disabled="{!AND(SelectedText == null && SelectedText == '')}" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="IdPanel">
      <apex:repeat var="TheID" value="{!CurrentList}"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{!TheID}" />;
      </apex:repeat>
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

How can I enable/disable commandButton based on the user have selected?

Here I'm checking to see if the User have selectedText and if the SelectedText is null or empty I want the commandButton to be disabled but the below code does disable the button but but never enable even though I have value in the SelectedText

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" rerender="IdPanel" 
disabled="{!AND(SelectedText == null && SelectedText == '')}" />
```

Comment: Are you rerendering the container (e.g. Apex:OutputPanel) that the commandButton is in?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: How can `SelectedText` be both null and an empty string at the same time? Would an `OR` not be better?

Comment: yes make no diff if I replace with `||` (OR)

Comment: Can you add more detail to what you want to happen? Do you want the button to be disabled as soon as they fill in the SelectedText text? or is this something that happens after they click Save?

Comment: well... what I'm trying to do is; enable/disable commandButton based on the SelectedText is empty or has value in it; so in other words if the SelectedText has no value then make commandButton disabled=true; otherwise, hope I'm clear :)

Comment: Do you want the button to be enabled as soon as they start typing in text in another field?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about your code, the following works assuming you have something like...

```
public String selectedText {
  get;
  set;
}
```

... In your controller.

See below:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction name="myActFunct" reRender="myPanel" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!selectedText}" onkeyup="myActFunct();" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" rerender="IdPanel" disabled="{!AND(SelectedText == null || SelectedText == '')}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

Basically you've got your inputText which, onkeyup, calls the ActionFunction which then rerenders the panel and then can check whether or not SelectedText is empty or not.

I've tested this and it should meet your requirements.

Good luck!

Comment: oops.. didnt see your answer before posting mine. Slight change in mine that instead of `actionFunction`, I used `actionSupport`. :-)

Comment: No problem! Both ways work which is the important thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple to achieve this. 
You just need to capture the keyup action and rerender the section containing the `CommandButton`. Use `ActionSupport` to capture the events as shown below.

Also added an `actionStatus` so that you know that the re-rendering is happening.

```
  <apex:pageBlock id="someblock">
        <apex:inputText value="{!SelectedText}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onkeyup" reRender="commandButtonPanel" status="status"/>
        </apex:inputText>

        <apex:outputPanel id="commandButtonPanel">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!enable}" disabled="{!SelectedText==null}" value="Submit"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:actionStatus startText="Re-evalutaing..."  stopText="Idle" id="status"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```